# Using .exists? in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exists

I'm working on Rails app that renders a signature in a particular position using:

```
 <div id="signature" style='position: absolute; left: <%= @document.template.signature_position.left %>px; top: <%= @document.template.signature_position.top %>px; '>
```

The problem is, if a user has not set the `signature_position` for the template and then attempts to open the show view they will get an error for `@document.template.signature_position.left` being nil.

The intended action would be to ignore the signature div entirely if `@document.template.signature_position.left` did not exist and render the rest of the page.  I attempted to use various solutions along the lines of:

```
`<%= if document.template.signature_position.left.exists?  %>
     <div id="signature" style='position: absolute; left: <%= @document.template.signature_position.left %>px; top: <%= @document.template.signature_position.top %>px; '>
     ..... extraneous functioning code  .....
<% end %>`
```

But I apparently am using incorrect syntax because regardless of my changes I am met with various errors, mostly things along the lines of " expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'".

Furious Googling has led to some interesting reading, but nothing useful so far.  Can someone help by suggesting the proper syntax for the intended action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off.

`<%=` inserts the value of an expression, but you just want to evaluate a conditional, so `<%` will suffice:

```
<% if document.template.signature_position.left.exists? %>
   ... code
<% end %>
```

You also have an unnecessary `?` in your conditional (which I removed from the example above).

I'm having a hard time coming up with "official" documentation for ERB syntax, but Puppet Labs has a nice guide [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#tags).

Comment: I thanks, the extra `?` was merely a typo on SO.  I attempted your suggestion above and received a `undefined local variable or method `document'` error.  I added `@document.....` to test and received a `undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass` error?

Comment: @PSCampbell guess you should check `nil?` or `blank?` instead of `exists?`.

Comment: @Cthulhu thanks, I was able to use your suggestion to create an `else` that fixed my issue.  Functioning code to come in an answer form.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) is used to check records in a database, so this is the kind of method you'd be using in a controller, rather than in a view.
- You more likely want to be using [Object#present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) (eg `@document.template.signature_position.left.present?`) to conditionally render some code in your view
- You're making a call to `@document.template.signature_position.top` based on the result of `@document.template.signature_position.left`.  Are you sure you don't need to check that both values exist first?
- Your view knows a lot about deep traversal of your `@document` object eg that it has a `template` that has a `signature_position` that has a `left` attribute.  In keeping with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), this knowledge can be cleaned out of your view and pushed further up the stack.

Here's my take on a *first round* refactor of your code (making a few assumptions):

In your model:

```
class Document < AR::Base
  def left_signature_position
    template.signature_position&.left
  end

  def top_signature_position
    template.signature_position&.top
  end

  def show_signature?
    left_signature_position.present? && 
      top_signature_position.present?
  end
end
```

then, in your view:

```
<% if @document.show_signature? %>
  <div id="signature" style='position: absolute; left: <%= @document.left_signature_position %>px; top: <%= @document.top_signature_position %>px; '>
<% end %>
```

Other further refactorings could include stuff like putting the code to generate the markup for a signature into a helper method, and/or adding delegation, decorator and/or helper methods for your `template` and `signature_position` classes to clean up the `template.signature_position&.top`-style methods that are now in the model.

Comment: You may want to note that the present method will actually load all records from the table into memory. If you only need one record for the view, it is terribly inefficient, especially if it is overused throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions of @nick and @cthulhu I was able to come up with a bit of a workaround that created the desired functionality:

```
<% if @document.template.signature_position.nil? %>
    <div></div>
<% else %>
     <div id="signature" style='position: absolute; left: <%= @document.template.signature_position.left %>px; top: <%= @document.template.signature_position.top %>px; '>
.... code ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why not just use `present?` unless you want empty `<div>`s